# JNI calls of C++ main app code from Java library

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, c++builder

I want to transmit data from Java to C++ with a `JNI call`.
The C++ code I want to call is a JNI call inside my main form `.cpp`.

I have to load the `.so` library of my C++ app in Java,
as C++Builder describes it this `.so` file is the `ProjectOutput` (located in `library\lib\armeabi-v7a\`.

I load the library as such :

```
public class McaScanner {

    //private static native void transmitScan(String barcode);  

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("libProjectTest");
    }

    //other static functions
}
```

Before I added the loading of this library everything worked fine and I could call Java code inside my C++ code through the `Delphi Native Interface` of this Java class.
But now when I call any method of this Java class, I get `EJNIFatal exception : "Invocation Error : method not found"`.

If I comment `loadLibrary()` it works back. What is cuasing this issue ?
Can't this type of library be loaded inside Java code ?

EDIT :

Ok once I tried to load inside `getInstance()` I could see the loading problem. `"lib"` was already append before `"libProjectTest"` so I should not have added it myself. 
 But I'm now getting the error:

```
No implementation found for void com.scanner.McaScanner.transmitScan(java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_scanner_McaScanner_transmitScan and Java_com_scanner_McaScanner_transmitScan__Ljava_lang_String_2)
```

Tho now it's crashing the app when before this same error wasn't.

**Implementation of my JNI Call in C++ in `com.embarcadero.ProjectTest` :**
(My Java class is in `com.scanner.McaScanner`)

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_scanner_McaScanner_transmitScan(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring barcode) {}
```

EDIT :

Would the problem be that I'm trying to load a library already in use in memory ?

Comment: It’s possible that **loadLibrary** failed, causing the static initializer to throw an error. I’d expect a class loader issue right after, but based on the JVM version wouldn’t be surprised to find symptoms as the ones you’re seeing.

Comment: @Timir
The error i get in logcat when using a function of that Java class :
`I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.scanner.McaScanner>`
But I get this error even before I instantiate my class with a `getInstance()`.
I tried with the load method but I get the same problem.
`static {}` field should be initialized on the first instance of the class so I don't know why it would cause problem before that.

`System.load(context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + "/armeabi-v7a/libProjectTest");`

Comment: From the doc : `static {}` blocks are called in the order they appear in the code.
Maybe that's the problme, gonna correct this by loading after having instiated singleton.